# File.Copy throws IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: c#, windows, m3u

This is more of a "why is this so" question as I've already worked around the issue.

I'm reading in an M3U playlist using [m3uParser](https://github.com/jefersonsv/m3uParser.NET). The playlist was created by adding files (located on a local NAS box) to VLC and saving the playlist.

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:298,Audio File Title
file://server-name/Music/01%20-%20Music%20-%20Can%27t%20Be%20Beat.flac
```

The purpose is to iterate through the playlist and copy the files to another location. No issues reading in the playlist.

```
var playlist = M3U.ParseFromFile(@"\\server-name\Music\Test\playlist.m3u");
var testPath = @"\\server-name\Music\Test";

foreach (var m in playlist.Medias)
{
  var fileName = Path.GetFileName(m.MediaFile);
  var dest = Path.Combine(testPath, Uri.UnescapeDataString(fileName));
  
  File.Copy(m.MediaFile, dest);
}
```

The issue comes with `File.Copy`. It throws an `IOException`:

> RuntimeMethodInfo
> `FileSystem.CopyFile (String sourceFullPath, String destFullPath, Boolean overwrite)`
>
> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. : 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\LINQPad8_fkqhopcf\shadow-26\file:\server-name\Music\01%20-%20Music%20-%20Can%27t%20Be%20Beat.flac'

[Other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56109567/the-filename-directory-name-or-volume-label-syntax-is-incorrect-file-copy) [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39255925/file-copy-error-c-sharp-ioexception-the-filename-directory-name-or-volume) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62120683/file-copy-throwing-throw-the-filename-directory-name-or-volume-label-syntax-i) deal with this exception, but the answer is always about making sure the destination specifies a *file*. In my case, I'm already taking care of defining a file as the destination. I also note the `Copy` method isn't complaining about file not found.

Is this just a case where Windows just can't handle the file location as defined in the playlist? My workaround assumes this is the case and reformats the media file into a "correct" network path.

Comment: Have you tried to map source and destination folder as a drive?

Comment: @MaciejLos No. And really, I don't think it's necessary. I do file moves/copies a lot on this NAS box. This is my first time using an M3U as a source, though. Normally I'm either specifying the network path as `@"\\server-name\...."` or receive it from `Directory.GetFiles` in the same structure.

Comment: I am a bit confused. You post an error message that clearly has the string "file:" halfway the path. This is not a valid windows path, they cannot contain the : character. How do you expect this to work? You need to strip off the file:// prefix before concatenating, seems like the code isn't doing that.

Comment: @Paul-Jan I'm not doing a concat operation. The file system is. I know it's not a valid file name. That's the point of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are `fileName` Or `dest` is `url` , `File.Copy` Not support Url

Maybe this code will work for you

```cs
WebClient client = new WebClient();

var playlist = M3U.ParseFromFile(@"\\server-name\Music\Test\playlist.m3u");
var testPath = @"\\server-name\Music\Test";

foreach (var m in playlist.Medias)
{
  var fileName = Path.GetFileName(m.MediaFile);
  var dest = Path.Combine(testPath, Uri.UnescapeDataString(fileName));
  
 client.DownloadFile(fileName , dest);
}
```

Comment: Neither `fileName` nor `dest` are `Uri`. The output of both `Path.GetFileName` and `Path.Combine` is `string`.